# Creating a regular expression that will match requirements in a string

Tags: php, regex, expression

## The issue

I need to write a regular expression that will match the following requirements in a string with the structure {A/B}.

**Requirements/Conditions:**

- A and B can only be exactly one of [UGWRB].
- A structure where U or G do not appear is invalid.
- A structure where both characters are equal is invalid.
- U or G must appear in the combination at least once.
- The structure can repeat or continue infinite times, as long as each following instance is still valid when read alone. (see valid matches below)

**Valid matches:**

- {U/G}{U/G}{U/G}
- {W/G}{U/B}
- {U/G}{U/B}
- {U/G}
- {G/U}
- {U/B}
- ...

**Invalid matches:**

- {U/U}{U/U}
- {U/U}{G/G}
- {U/G}{U/U}
- {U/G}{R/B}
- {G/G}
- {R/B}
- {W/R}
- {B/W}
- ...

## My attempt

This is what I have gotten so far, but out of all the combinations of UGWRB, I'm only getting 8 matches out of 14.

`{([UG])(?(1)|\w)\/(?(1)\w|[UG])}`

Comment: You haven't incorporated `WRB` anywhere.

Comment: and why `{W/G}{U/B}` is invalid?

Comment: @AbraCadaver what do you mean?

Comment: @revo it's a mistake, sorry.

Comment: Why try to stuff all this complexity into a single regular expression? Your code will be much clearer, simpler and more maintainable if you split the string and process each of its sub-components.

Comment: I generally avoid using regexs for this very reason (also why I'm not that good at writing them beyond simpler stuff), but this is a personal tool which I probably will never have to touch ever again and I wanted something quick and dirty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to work with lookaheads both negative and positive in order to accomplish the task:

```
^(?:{(?=[^{}]*[UG])([UGWRB])\/(?!\1)(?1)})+$
```

See [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/UgvS4D/3)

Note that `m` flag should be set.

Regex breakdown:

- `^` Match start of input string
- `(?:` Start of non-capturing group

  - `{` Match `{` literally
  - `(?=` Start of positive lookahead

    - `[^{}]*[UG]` Look for [UG] in combination
  - `)` End of lookahead
  - `([UGWRB])` Match and capture a letter from character class
  - `\/(?!\1)(?1)` Match `/` and see if next char is not the same as recently captured one
  - `}` Match `}` literally
- `)+` End of group, repeat at least once
- `$` Match end of input string

Comment: Marked as solution because 1) works as expected 2) slightly faster than other solution according to regex101 and 3) more readable than other solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
^(?!.*{([UGWRB])\/\1})(?:{(?(?=[UG]).\/[UGWRB]|[WRB]\/[UG])})+$
```

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4huT2n/1)**

Explanation:

- `^` - matches the start of the string
- `(?!.*{([UGWRB])\/\1})` - negative lookahead to make sure that the structures like `{G/G}` or `{U/U}` or `{R/R}` are not present anywhere in the string
- `{` - matches `{`
- `(?(?=[UG]).\/[UGWRB]|[WRB]\/[UG])` - [Regex Conditional](https://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html). If the current position is followed by either `U` or `G`, then the match that character followed by `/` and the character class `[UGWRB]`. Otherwise, match the character class `[WRB]` followed by `/` followed by `U` or `G`
- `}` - matches `}`
- `+` - matches 1+ occurrences of the above sub-sequence `(?:{(?(?=[UG]).\/[UGWRB]|[WRB]\/[UG])})`
- `$` - matches the end of the string

Comment: Thanks, this is working as intended, however the other answer is faster and cleaner.
Sorry for the late reply.